# How to disable Firefox promt "firefox automatically sends some data to mozilla so that we can improve your experience" for the default profile?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium2 for automated web testing. After a while (don't know how long it takes) a prompt appears on the bottom to choose data choices.
"firefox automatically sends some data to mozilla so that we can improve your experience"
How can I disable this prompt (or better any prompts) by default? And is Selenium2 using always a copy of the default profile?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks problem with your program or site or your firefox version. Update firefox please.

Comment: Updating firefox is in my opinion not the solution because not every version of ff is compatible with selenium (look at selenium release notes). Also the prompt is something, which is shown in every version of firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prompt relates to the "Firefox Health Report", which is checked by default in

> Open Menu > Options > Options (or Tools > Options) > Advanced > Data Choices

In Selenium, you may disable this prompt by setting the following three properties in the Firefox profile to false:

- datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled
- datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled
- datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun

Here is a demonstration in Python:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()           
profile.set_preference('datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled', False)
profile.set_preference('datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled', False)
profile.set_preference('datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun', False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

DanEng answer is about disabling the health report itself, but (at least in a standard Browser) the notification is still showing.
I use fresh Firefox profile for testing and this annoyed me.

To hide the notification in Mozilla Quantum (not sure if this would work in Selenium), create user.js file in profile folder with this lines:

```
pref("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAcceptedVersion", 2);
pref("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyNotifiedTime", "9000000000000");
```

Both lines are required.
The time from about now was 1533619817422, when I tried 10000000000, it did ask again.
My guess is it's asking again in periods. Using 9000000000000 works for me.

I also added these settings:

```
// Two pages will open on first run:

// Disabling first start web page in first tab:
// https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/61.0.1/firstrun/
pref("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "61.0.1");

// Disabling first start web page in second tab:
// https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/
pref("toolkit.telemetry.reportingpolicy.firstRun", false);

// hiding the tip showing 4 times below address bar, when selected:
// "Firefox Tip: Get help finding things! Look for the "magnifier" next to search suggestions."
pref("browser.urlbar.timesBeforeHidingSuggestionsHint", 0);
```

Comment: thanks. The `datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyNotifiedTime` seems to be what was missing. Now, even though telemetry is (theoretically) disabled, that nagging pop-up does not show anymore (or at least it will take a very long time to)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom profile for Firefox, set it up however you want, then call it from your tests:

Look here for more information:

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

https://automatictester.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/selenium-running-custom-firefox-profile/

Comment: thanks for the hint. but does a new profile prevent any prompts like these? Think I have to know which specific preferences I have to set (see about:config)
Or is it enough to deselect all data choices (telemetry, health report, (performance))?

Comment: I believe you should be able to create the profile, configure it to have Telemetry and the other choices turned off, then configure your tests to use the new custom profile as shown in the links above.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try